# How to test an application as JUnit-Plugin test in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit, rcp, eclipse-pde

I am trying to set up a JUnit Plugin test for a RCP-Application. Thereby I am using Tycho (0.18), maven 3.0.2, eclipse INDIGO and JUnit4.

When I configure a Plugin Test, the to be tested application starts as expected, but the chosen test case does not run. Whereby I do not get any error or exception messages.

Because I did not find anything with google, I would be very happy if someone could provide some helpful information or tutorials.

**Update:** I have found this tutorial: [How to JUnitPluginTests](http://wiki.bioclipse.net/index.php?title=How_to_write_JUnit_plugin_tests). But the UnitTests didn't start without any error message...

I have the assumption that the JUnit-Plugin-Test launcher does not work in a correct manner. Because I have to define my application separately in the arguments tab, else the following error appears:

> Application "org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.nonuithreadtestapplication" could not be found in the registry

Comment: Some logs would look appropriate here.

Comment: There is no log. The to be tested application starts, but the chosen test case not. - Without any feedback.

Comment: How do you choose the test case? How is the test class called?

Comment: via the test tab of eclipse JUnit-Plugin-Test-Menu: `Run a single test: ...`

Comment: So you are using the Eclipse PDE to run the test? In this case, Tycho isn't involved at all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked Christian Pontesegger's [tutorial](http://codeandme.blogspot.fr/2012/12/tycho-build-7-plug-in-unit-tests.html) on Tycho, which includes a post about tests?

Answer (score 0):

I had apparently the same problem.  I tried a number of things, but what worked for me was:

- Open the run configuration
- Switch to the Main tab
- Select 'Run an application'
- Select '[No Application] - Headless mode'

I didn't need to run my product and this allowed the JUnit plug-in test runner to locate the unit tests.